# position of menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I have menu that scrolls vertically with the page however it also scrolls horizontally if you move horizontal scroll bar to the right you will see what i mean.

I need to eliminate horizontal scrolling and only keep vertical, any easy way to do it with css?

http://jsfiddle.net/NNnkU/4/

Comment: Your table has a fixed width of `1000px`. It will need to scroll horizontally if the browser window is less than that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add in a width to the page_frame of 100% as below

```
.page_frame {
    background-color:#006600;
    color:#ffffff;
    width: 100%;
}
```